# Question regarding two statements in Titchmarsh p. 266

Tags: number-theory, improper-integrals, integral-inequality

I am currently reading Titchmarsh's book about the Riemann Zeta function and came across two little problems at p. 266:

$1)$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2n^2\pi x^2 sin\, \delta} = O \left(x^{-1}\delta^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right) $$

This is what I've got so far  with the variables beging: $\, x\in (1, G)$ where $G=e^{1/H}$ and $H\geq 1$

\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2n^2\pi x^2 sin \delta} \leq& \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2y^2\pi x^2 sin\, \delta} \, dy \\
\leq & \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2y\pi x^2 sin \delta} \,  dy\\
= &  \frac{1}{\pi \, sin\, \delta}   
\end{align}

But I do not know how to complete the inequality.

$2)$ $$ O\left( \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}H^2(G-1) \right) + O\left(\frac{\delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{log \, G}  \right) = O \left( H \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right) $$

Putting $G=e^{\frac{1}{H}}$ on the left hand side I get for some constants $C,K >0$

$$  C\delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}H^2(G-1)  + K\frac{\delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{log \, G} = H \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}(CH (e^{\frac{1}{H}}-1)+K) $$

I do not see why $CH (e^{\frac{1}{H}}-1)+K$ can become constant.

I think those are two little problems but I really do not see what trick gives me the desired result. I appreciate any hints. Thank you in advance.

Comment: He proved before that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x} \sim x^{-1/2}$ as $x \to 0^+$, starting from $\theta(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x} $ and the Poisson summation formula to obtain $\theta(1/x) = x^{-1/2} \theta(x)$ (chapter II the proofs of the functional equation). In general he says that he is using eq 2.1.x when he does, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2n^2\pi x^2 sin \delta} \leq \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2y^2\pi x^2 sin\, \delta} \, dy = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{\sin{\delta}}} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-2\pi u^2} \, du $$
by putting $u = yx\sqrt{\sin{\delta}}$, and then $\sin{\delta} = O(\delta)$ as $\delta \to 0$.

Second: (as $H \to \infty$?)
$$ H(e^{1/H}-1) = H\left(1+\frac{1}{H}+O\left(\frac{1}{H^{2}}\right)-1\right) = 1+ O(H^{-1}) $$
by the Taylor series of $e^{x}$ around $x=0$.

Comment: see also my comment above